# How to format the JSON?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to output json data from a pandas dataframe directly into [dcc.store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) (plotly-dash component), which is the output with id 'intermediate-value'. So, I made a dictionary, and I dumped the JSON. I keep getting this error:

```
Expected type: (<class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
Received value of type <class 'str'>
```

I understand it says I am passing it a string, and that I should be passing it a tuple (or?) a list. What I am unsure of is how to edit my code to match the data structure it desires. Could anyone provide insight, I included my function in question below:

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output('intermediate-value', 'data')
    ],
    [
        Input("keyword-selection", "value"),
        Input("status-selection", "value")
    ]
)
def color_map(keyword_selected, status_selected):
    local_df = df_xy_coord[df_xy_coord["active"] == status_selected].copy() if status_selected != "All" else df_xy_coord

    color_index = 0
    for keyword in keyword_selected:
        local_df.loc[local_df["keyword"] == keyword, 'color'] = colors[color_index]
        color_index += 1

    color_dictionary = dict( zip( local_df.keyword, local_df.color ) )
    return( json.dumps(color_dictionary, indent = 4) )
```

Comment: aside: return is a keyword, not a fn, so you don't want parantheses

Comment: Fixed that, appreciate the knowledge!

Comment: I've never used plotly/dash, but do you want the lists in the decorator?  the examples on that link just have multiple args.  could be talking nonsense, though

Comment: Should not make a difference, I messed with that recently and got the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a tuple in Python (the comma is necessary for Python to parse it as a tuple of size 1):

```
return (color_dictionary,  )
```

To return a list in Python:

```
return [color_dictionary]
```

`json.dumps` serializes an object (e.g. a `dict`) to a JSON formatted `str`.
You can serialise your dict into a JSON string first and then return it inside a tuple or list following the examples above.
See docs for json.dumps [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: Ahh this is correct, thank you. I was overcomplicating it with my previous attempts at solving

Comment: Since your callback has your `Output` inside a `list`, you need to also return a list, as shown in this answer.